# How to add breakpoints to dynamically loaded JS files with timestamp appended to the name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I have this problem adding break points to files with changing files names in Chrome.
xyz.js?*=123456 for the first load and xyz.js?*=123789 for the second load, so it is impossible to add any break points for it. Do you know any tricks which would solve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to put the following line where you want to break: `debugger;`

Comment: I can't modify the file content, it is on customers page.

Comment: Well, what if you try to disable cache for current page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Comment: It is not about the page cache, the file itself is loaded with the appended timestamp to the filename.

Comment: Yes, it's called 'cache buster' and main purpose is to make sure that fresh copy of files is loaded always, and not cached one.